Syncing Values On-Demand with Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider When spec.configuration.refresh is Disabled
I have set spec.configuration.refresh to false in the Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider configuration. Could you provide guidance on how to manually sync the values whenever needed?
I have configured the Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider (AAC) on our AKS cluster with the following refresh settings:
refresh:
  enabled: true
  interval: 3m

We are considering increasing the refresh interval to 5 hours in our lower environments to reduce polling traffic. However, we need to ensure that any changes in the key values in the App Configuration are promptly reflected in the microservice's configmap.
When testing, I found that manually reapplying the AzureAppConfigurationProvider YAML (without any modifications) does not trigger an immediate update of the configmap. The changes are only reflected after the 5-hour interval.
Is there a way to force an on-demand update of the configmap when a key value changes in the App Configuration?
Additionally, for another use case in our lower environments, we are considering disabling the refresh feature entirely:
spec:
  configuration:
    refresh: false

In this scenario, how can we manually trigger an update to the target configmap when there is a change in the key-value pair in the App Configuration service?

You mentioned that reapplying the AzureAppConfigurationProvider YAML does not trigger an immediate update, and you have refresh set to 5hrs, and you want to manually trigger a sync before the refresh interval. Restart the Azure App Configuration Provider Pod. Restarting the pod will force a sync, even if the interval hasn’t passed. Here are few potential workaround solutions to your requirement. Solution 1 (restart the pod) which is the simplest for on-demand refresh without needing complex scripting. Solution 2 (custom script) automates the pod restart.

I would suggest to make the changes and manually Trigger Sync with kubectl to force an on-demand update of the ConfigMap to manually sync the values whenever needed.
Assuming you already have your Azure App Configuration ready

Since you have set spec.configuration.refresh to false, in order to manually trigger the sync,  delete the Azure App Configuration Provider pod, and Kubernetes will automatically recreate it. This will force the provider to re-fetch the values from Azure App Configuration and update the target ConfigMap.


This should show the updated key-values that have been synced from Azure App Configuration.
References:

Tutorial: Use dynamic configuration in Azure Kubernetes Service
Restart pod for App Configuration

